# Not entire rows are loaded while using spark

Tags: r

I tried to load the data using `spark_read_csv()` using below

`spark_read_csv(sc,name = "as", path = "D:/New folder/Copy.csv",header = TRUE)`

It is working, but the all rows are not getting extracted. There are 200k rows and only 1000 rows are extracted. Why?

Comment: `There are 2 lakh rows and only 1000 rows are extracted.` - why do you think this is the case?

Comment: Not sure. While extracting through spark, I am getting this

Comment: My question is why do you think you only get 1000 rows. See what more info you can provide...

Comment: I understood your question. Not sure what you meant? Unfortunately there is no much info here :)